# Error - NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to display an array as options in a menu drop down but I am getting the error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

HTML code:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let type of exportTemplates" value="{{ type.id }}">
    {{ type.label }}
 </mat-option>
```

And the array looks likes this:
[image]

TS code:

```
exportTemplates = [];
const subs = this.configService.state$.subscribe((config: any) => {
            this.exportTemplates = config.templates.types;
        });
        this.subscription.push(subs);
```

Comment: That is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

How about merging all the items in an array

```
list.map(item => Object.keys(item).map(key => item[key]))[0]
```

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-merge-ngfor?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference